# Permissions to read from BigQuery __TABLE__ metatables

Tags: google-bigquery, google-iam

What permissions does a service account needs to read from BigQuery `__TABLE__` tables? Our scenario is that we want to grant the service account collecting storage stats from our BigQuery projects minimum necessary permissions. Ideally it shouldn't be able to read the data from BQ tables but still it needs to read the `__TABLE__` tables from all our datasets. We tried granting metadataViewer permissions but that didn't work, still getting 403.

Answer (score 1):

> Ideally it shouldn't be able to read the data from BQ tables but still it needs to read the `__TABLE__` tables from all our datasets.

Currently, you cannot grant permissions on tables, views, columns, or rows. A dataset is the lowest level resource that supports access controls in BigQuery.
-- [source](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/dataset-access-controls) --

Therefore you will need to grant `roles/bigquery.dataViewer` to the service account.

You might also need to grant a second permission. Under the hood the code that executes with service account credentials will be making API calls. I don't know the details applicable to your case, but the code will likely use one of the basic REST objects (such as [Job](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/reference/rest/v2/Job) object) to make the calls. And will likely need another permission(s) that come under umbrella of `roles/bigquery.jobUser` or similar role.

Comment: I understand that BQ permissions are granted at the project or dataset level. Still the `__TABLE__` tables are not normal tables, as effectively they contain dataset metadata. It would make sense the metadataViewer permission to be enough. 

Executing the jobs is not a problem for us, the question is specifically about getting access to the metadata tables.

Comment: Assuming you meant `__TABLES__` (plural), yes the table is special. But it doesn’t prevent it from having the data it holds separated from the metadata attached to it. You can see the former by executing statement `Select * from dataset1.__TABLES__`  and the latter by using the command `bq show --format=prettyjson dataset1.__TABLES__`. Taking into account this clear separation, it would make sense to assume data permission is for data and metadata permission for metadata.

Answer (score 1):

The required permissions to query `__TABLES__` are the same as to query any regular tables. Thus, the `roles/bigquery.dataViewer` role viewer at dataset level should be enough.

Since your requirement is to only grant access to this particular table's data, but not to the user generated tables, a possible workaround is to create an [**authorized view**](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/share-access-views) in a separate dataset. The view will have dataViewer access to your current dataset and the user will have dataViewer access to the dataset containing the view.